# Using async package inside blue bird promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, bluebird

I would like to know if I'm using a async inside a promise, like this:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function(file, callback) {
   //
   //
 }, function(result) {
   //
 });
});
```

I'm doing this because I need process an maximum of 3000 files, but if I pass 9000, I need process everything before call the other function in my stack.

For the example I'm using the new Promise, but I'm using promisifyAll in my real code. Which is the "same"

---

I have this MainObject:

```
var MyObject = {}
```

Inside with, I have 4 steps, and I'm using promisifyAll because I need wait one step finish before call the other, like this:

```
var MyObject = {
  stepOne: function(files, callback) {
  },

  stepTwo: function(files, callback) {
  },

  stepThree: function(files, callback) {
  },

  stepFour: function(files, callback) {
  }
};

Promise.promisifyAll(MyObject);
```

The problem is, in which step (I'm dealing with files here) I just can allow the program run 3.000 Asynchronous, so to achieve this, I'm using the following:

```
async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function() {

}, function(result) {
});
```

So, the final code would be:

```
var MyObject = {
  stepOne: function(files, callback) {
    async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function() {

     }, function(result) {
    });
  },

  stepTwo: function(files, callback) {
    async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function() {

     }, function(result) {
    });
  },

  stepThree: function(files, callback) {
    async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function() {

     }, function(result) {
    });
  },

  stepFour: function(files, callback) {
    async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function() {

     }, function(result) {
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: FYI Node.js can only process 4 file system operations in parallel or at maximum 128 if you run with [`UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=128`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html) environment variable, so concurrency of 3000 doesn't make sense

Comment: I'm working with files, but i'm not using fs at all. I'm using child_process with a bash script @Esailija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Bluebird's `Promise.map()` and pass the concurrency option:

```
Promise.map(files, function(file) {
    // process the file here, return result or promise of result
}, {concurrency: 3000}).then(...)
```

Documentation and code example [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).

---

You could, of course use async inside a promise, though I would not recommend it:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function(file, callback) {
   //
   //
   callback(null, result);
 }, function(err, results) {
     if (err) {
         reject(err);
     } else {
         resolve(results);
     }
 });
});
```

---

Again, I recommend using `Promise.map()`:

```
var MyObject = {
  stepOne: function(files) {
    return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
        // process a file
        // return result or promise of result
    }, {concurrency: 3000});
  },

  stepTwo: function(files) {
    return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
        // process a file
        // return result or promise of result
    }, {concurrency: 3000});
  },

  stepThree: function(files) {
    return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
        // process a file
        // return result or promise of result
    }, {concurrency: 3000});
  },

  stepFour: function(files) {
    return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
        // process a file
        // return result or promise of result
    }, {concurrency: 3000});
};
```

Then, there is no need for `promisifyAll()` as the methods already use promises.

```
MyObject.stepOne(files).then(MyObject.stepTwo).then(MyObject.stepThree).then(MyObject.stepFour);
```

Comment: But i would still have a promise inside a promise, right? it's okay to do this?

Comment: @JoãoCalvin - Yes, you can use a promise inside a promise, but you do have to do it correctly for it to work properly.  If you can include your ACTUAL code in your question, we can advise more specifically.  Returning promises from within `.then()` handlers is a key feature of promises for chaining promises so it absolutely can be done.

Comment: hei @jfriend00.. i update my code, i think now you can understand all the picture >.<

Comment: @JoãoCalvin - I still recommend you use `Promise.map()` as I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Now i get it! I didn't know that i can return just one promise like this.